# Create an Azure AppendBlobClient logfile

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am attempting to write log file entries to an Azure Blob file using the [AppendBlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/appendblobclient?view=azure-node-latest):

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = process.env["FOO_CONNECTION_STRING"];
const FOO_CONTAINER = process.env["FOO_CONTAINER_NAME"];

exports.handler = async (context, req) => {
    // setup logging to Azure Blob Container
    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);

    const logFileName = "log" + moment().tz('America/Chicago').format("YYYYMMDD");
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(FOO_CONTAINER);
    containerClient.create(logFileName);
    const loggingClient = containerClient.getAppendBlobClient(logFileName);

    const orders = req.body

    // iterate over collection of orders, executing an insert for each
    for (let idx = 0; idx < orders.length; idx++) {
       // do an insert, capture the results, create a log entry
       await loggingClient.appendBlock(logEntry, logEntry.length);
    }
        
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify( { insertionCount: orders.length })
    };
}
```

However, I am struggling to understand how to create the initial, empty blob logfile (of type AppendBlob).  If I execute this, I get an error that the `The specified blob does not exist.` so obviously, `containerClient.create(logFileName);` is not correct. Anyone use **AppendBlobClient** that could point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, was attempting the create on the wrong object.  It should be:

```
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);

const logFileName = "log" + moment().tz('America/Chicago').format("YYYYMMDD");
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(FOO_CONTAINER);
const loggingClient = containerClient.getAppendBlobClient(logFileName);
await loggingClient.create();
```

Comment: you probably want to use the `createIfNotExists` function